# "go to university" vs. "go to an university"

Tags: meaning

consider these

> Michael went to an American university last year
>
> Michael went to America to go to university last year
>
> Michael went to an American university to started to get a degree last year

I guess both are grammatically correct and an English native speaker told me the former sounds more natural.

However, in contrast with the latter, the former does not convey the idea that Michael is about study at university, he might work at that university.

Is my understanding right?

To convey that idea, I put some more and got the third sentence, do native speakers say it that way?

Comment: In British English, to 'go to university' means to study there.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Yes. Thank you. That's why I put the second one there. The question is whether the first one could convey that idea.

Comment: Since most university courses last for more than one year, saying that Michael went to one 'last year' reads and sounds oddly.

Comment: Even if you say _go to (a particular) university_, I think the default meaning would be _to study there_, unless the context indicated that the person worked there.

Comment: Note that, until recently, _go to (a) university_ was a distinctively British English expression. See [Lynn Murphy's blog](https://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2022/01/uk-to-us-word-of-year-2021-university.html) about choosing it as her "UK-to-US Word of the Year 2021"

Comment: The words "former" and "latter" refer to two things. You have a list of three things, so it's unclear what "former" and "latter" refer to. Do you mean the first and the last?

Comment: University is spoken like youniversity. So it’s not an university but a university.

Answer (score 1):

The emphasis is rather different.

The first says he studied at an American University.

The second says he travelled to America.  (And the reason for him travelling to America was to study at university there).

So you could use the first, even if Michael was American: Suppose he studied in Germany for his first degree, then he came home, then *he went to an American university* for postgraduate studies. In that case Michael didn't go to America to go to university.

However both suggest that he studied at university.  Without other context "go to university" means to study there.

Your last sentence is incorrect.  I suppose you mean "to start to get a degree", but that is not really idiomatic.  You could have " ... to study history." for example.

Not that in your title, "An university" is wrong, as university is pronounced /ju:ni.../ with a consonant sound.  It must be "A university".